# Trigger returns results from all rows instead of one row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a trigger on the `employeepayhistory` table. Whenever I update the `RATE` column in the table its effect on the monthly salary should be displayed, but instead it gives me the monthly salary of the whole record if I update one record. Please help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MONTHTRG
ON HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Rate MONEY
   SELECT @Rate=Rate FROM INSERTED
   SELECT 'MONTHSAL'=Rate*PayFrequency*30 FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
END
```

Comment: Add where clause oin the trigger on the PK column or identity column.

Comment: Please note that triggers should *not* be used to return data. As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.100).aspx) says, "a trigger is designed to check or change data based on a data modification or definition statement".

Answer (score 0):

You also need to give the where condition, typically you'll

```
DECLARE @Id bigint
SET @Id = (SELECT Id from Inserted)
SELECT 'MONTHSAL' = Rate * PayFrequency*30 From HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory where Humanresources.EmployeeID=@Id
```

This will work if the Primary key is called 'Id' and ofcourse, is unique. You can also do this with a Unique key(which should be Non-NULL)